# Inertiajs version of axios interceptor to work on SPA first load

Tags: vue.js, inertiajs

When I was using laravel/vue without inertia I was able to intercept the axios call, and see if a particular key existed in the data. When it did, I would use dispatchEvent to trigger a method in a component included in the layout, which was listening.

Now that I'm using [Inertia](https://inertiajs.com/) I can only trigger this on router change. On a reload or by visiting using the URL in a new tab it doesn't trigger.

I have tried [every router event](https://inertiajs.com/events).

`active_styles` is sent on page load (reload or first-view); I can see it in Vue tools in chrome. It doesn't show up in the network tab unless I visit the page using the router.

I use this for when the page changes

```
import { router } from '@inertiajs/vue3'

router.on('finish', (event) => {
    if (router.page.props.active_styles){
        eventBus.emit('refreshActiveStyles', {'styles': router.page.props.active_styles});
    }
});
```

This looks for `active_styles` in `props`, and uses eventBus to trigger a method in Style component that's listening for it.

With axios I used `axios.interceptors.response.use`, which worked every time, but now the props are loaded with intertia, not after the page has loaded.

What I don't want to do is - on every page - add `active_styles` to the props, pass that to the Layout component, and have Layout pass that to the Style component that uses it. Nor do I want to include the Style component in every page, and again have to pass the data via props on the page to props on the component. Both are repetitive and it's required for every page.

So how do I do it? It only works when router is changed once the SPA has loaded. There must be a way - on first load - to find the correct data and trigger that function.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Leaving an answer in case someone else has the same issue.

Remove the router event, and the eventBus listener.

In the Styles component, `mounted` is triggered every time the router changes, and when it's loaded with no router change.

Inertia has a `usePage` utility, which can be used in `mounted`.

*Styles.vue*

```
import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/vue3'

export default { 
    ...
    mounted(){
        const active_styles = usePage().props.active_styles;
        this.someFunction(active_styles);
    },
    ...
};
```